# Biot-Savart Operator in R^3 for Euler equations

Tags: calculus, derivatives, indefinite-integrals, fluid-dynamics

I have a question concerning the Biot-Savart law: For the 3D Euler equations, that is,

$\partial_t u + (\nabla \cdot u) u = -\nabla p $

$\nabla \cdot u = 0$,

the Biot-Savart law declares a relation between the velocity and its curl, =curl() via the Biot-Savart operator, that is

$u(x) = \int \omega(y) \times \frac{(x-y)}{|x-y|^3} dy$.

Now, my question is, when one applies $\nabla_x$ on both sides of the equation, that is, $\nabla_x u(x)= \nabla_x(\int \omega(y) \times \frac{(x-y)}{|x-y|^3} dy)$, this should be apparently equal to the following:

$\nabla_x(\int \omega(y) \times \frac{(x-y)}{|x-y|^3} dy) = \int \omega(y) \times (\frac{(x)}{|y|^3} - 3 \frac{<y,x>}{|y|^5}dy$.

I have tried many different derivations, but I can't really seem to find the final result.

I would really appreciate if someone could help, thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you write expression for $\omega$ clearly. Can you make it clear what is that you are trying to prove  starting from what ? Thanks. Are u trying to prove  $\nabla_x u(x) = \int ((\nabla \times u)(y) ) \nabla_x \left( \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^3} \right) dy$ starting from $ u(x) = \int ((\nabla \times u)(y) ) \left( \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^3} \right) dy$ or starting from $\partial_t u = -\nabla p$ ? Please also post ur attempt to replicate Biot Savart law with $\nabla_x u$. For example, we  have $\partial_t \nabla_x u = - \nabla_x \nabla p$. So just repeat the derivation with $u$ replaced by $\nabla_x u$.

Comment: Also please give the definition of $p$.

Comment: So, as I already defined before, the Euler equations in R^3 are given by the aforementioned equations. You can define the vorticity $\omega = \nabla \times u$. Then, without going into too much detail, you can basically go on and relate the velocity and vorticity via the Biot-savart operator, then you'll get then expression: $u(x) = \int \omega(y) \times (\frac{(x-y}{|x-y|^3})dy$. Now, applying $\nabla_x u(x)$ on both sides, one gets the term u(x) = $\int \omega (y) \times \frac{x}{|y|^3} - 3\frac{<y,x>}{|x-y|^5})dy$. I basically need help getting to this term!

Comment: P is pressure term

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega(y) = [\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3]$.

$$V = \omega(y) \times \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^3} = $$
$$ \left[\omega_2 \frac{(x_3-y_3)}{|x-y|^3}- \omega_3 \frac{(x_2-y_2)}{|x-y|^3}, \omega_1 \frac{(x_3-y_3)}{|x-y|^3}- \omega_3 \frac{(x_1-y_1)}{|x-y|^3}, \omega_1 \frac{(x_2-y_2)}{|x-y|^3}- \omega_2 \frac{(x_1-y_1)}{|x-y|^3} \right]$$

$$\nabla_x V = -3\left(\omega_2 \frac{x_1(x_1-y_1)(x_3-y_3)}{|x-y|^5}- \omega_3 \frac{x_1(x_1-y_1)(x_2-y_2)}{|x-y|^5} \right)- 3\left(\omega_1 \frac{x_2(x_2-y_2)(x_3-y_3)}{|x-y|^5}- \omega_3 \frac{x_2(x_2-y_2)(x_1-y_1)}{|x-y|^5}\right) -3\left( \omega_1 \frac{x_3(x_3-y_3)(x_2-y_2)}{|x-y|^5}- \omega_2 \frac{x_3(x_3-y_3)(x_1-y_1)}{|x-y|^5} \right)$$

Now i think we need to combine the coefficient of $\omega_i$ and match the coefficient of $\omega_i$ between LHS and RHS. Can u calculate the cross product of RHS similarly and post in the question. I will then try to see if both matches. I can do it now itself but i feel there are some typos in your right hand side for example denominator is based on $|y|$. Is it $|x-y|$ ? Can u please fix typos and post the cross product of right hand side in a similar fashion ?